# Why if $T$ is not a bounded operator then exists $ (x_n) $ that converges to $ 0_{X} $ for which $ \| T(x_n) \| \geq n^2 $ for all $ n $?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be normed spaces.

Suppose that $ T: X \to Y $ is a linear operator and assume that $T$ is not bounded.

Why with these assumptions can I say that exists a sequence $ (x_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ in $ X $ that converges in norm to $ 0_{X} $ but for which $ \| T(x_{n}) \|_{Y} \geq n^{2} $ for all $ n \in \mathbb{N} $?

I know that if $T$ is not bounded then it is not continous in $0_X$, so there is a sequence 
 $ (x_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ in $ X $ that converges in norm  to $ 0_{X} $ but for which  that$(T(x_{n}))_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ does not converge in norm to $0_Y$. How can I conclude that $ \| T(x_{n}) \|_{Y} \geq n^{2} $ for all $ n \in \mathbb{N} $?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can't. But, there is a sequence $x_n$ of norm-one elements with $\Vert T x_n\Vert>n^3$. Consider the sequence $(x_n/n)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n\in {\mathbb N}$ be arbitrary. Since $T$ is not bounded there exists a vector $y_n$
such that $\| y_n\| \leq 1$ but $ \| T y_n\| > n^3$. Now let $x_n=\frac{1}{n} y_n$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer...the fact that for every $n$ exists such $y_n$ is it a consequence of the fact that if T is not bounded then $sup_{||x||\leq 1}||T(x)||$ is not finite? Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, you are right! If $T$ is not bounded, then for any positive $c$ there must exists a vector $y$ of norm $1$ (or less) such that $\| Ty\|>c$.

Comment: Many thanks for your help!